# Group index by minute and compute average

Tags: python, pandas, average, minute, pandas-groupby

So I have a pandas dataframe called 'df' and I want to remove the seconds and just have the index in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format. But also the minutes are then grouped and the average for that minute is displayed.

So I want to turn this dataFrame

```
                        value
2015-05-03 00:00:00     61.0
2015-05-03 00:00:10     60.0
2015-05-03 00:00:25     60.0
2015-05-03 00:00:30     61.0
2015-05-03 00:00:45     61.0
2015-05-03 00:01:00     61.0
2015-05-03 00:01:10     60.0
2015-05-03 00:01:25     60.0
2015-05-03 00:01:30     61.0
2015-05-03 00:01:45     61.0
2015-05-03 00:02:00     61.0
2015-05-03 00:02:10     60.0
2015-05-03 00:02:25     60.0
2015-05-03 00:02:40     60.0
2015-05-03 00:02:55     60.0
2015-05-03 00:03:00     59.0
2015-05-03 00:03:15     59.0
2015-05-03 00:03:20     59.0
2015-05-03 00:03:35     59.0
2015-05-03 00:03:40     60.0
```

into this dataFrame

```
                        value
2015-05-03 00:00        60.6
2015-05-03 00:01        60.6
2015-05-03 00:02        60.2
2015-05-03 00:03        59.2
```

ive tried code like

```
df['value'].resample('1Min').mean()
```

or

```
df.index.resample('1Min').mean()
```

but this does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: For me it works perfectly. You get some error?

Comment: df.index.resample('1Min').mean() gives the error AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'resample' and df['value'].resample('1Min').mean() does not give an error but does not give the desired outcome, nothing changes i dont get the averages and the seconds are still there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need first convert index to [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
#another solution
#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

print (df['value'].resample('1Min').mean())
#another same solution
#print (df.resample('1Min')['value'].mean())
2015-05-03 00:00:00    60.6
2015-05-03 00:01:00    60.6
2015-05-03 00:02:00    60.2
2015-05-03 00:03:00    59.2
Freq: T, Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Another solution with seting values of seconds in index to `0` by `astype`:

```
print (df.groupby([df.index.values.astype('<M8[m]')])['value'].mean())
2015-05-03 00:00:00    60.6
2015-05-03 00:01:00    60.6
2015-05-03 00:02:00    60.2
2015-05-03 00:03:00    59.2
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I allready have df.index = df.index.to_datetime() in my code, does that not convert to a datetimeindex?

Comment: Do you try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` ?

Comment: ok so the code i really wanted was df = df['value'].resample('1Min').mean(), thank you, will accept your answer in 4 minutes time!

Comment: Glad can help you. `df.resample('1Min')['value'].mean()` is same as `df['value'].resample('1Min').mean()`, I add it to answer.

Comment: how can i convert the result into a data frame as i need to plot it. the dtype is float as of now. @jezrael

Comment: @ak3191 - I think for ploting it is not necessary, use `s = df.groupby([df.index.values.astype('<M8[m]')])['value'].mean()` and `s.plot()`. But if want `DataFrame` use `rint (df.groupby([df.index.values.astype('<M8[m]')])['value'].mean().reset_index())`